# Yii Insert Multiple Records and Return the Ids (INSERT IGNORE)

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am having some issues trying to get the ID of the last inserted rows when using multiple inserts.

I wish to insert records into the DB for example using:

```
$sql ="INSERT IGNORE INTO test(date, src, dst) VALUES ('2014-01-15','1','2') ('2014-01-12','9','2')";
$added =  Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->execute();
```

This is great as I have a dynamic number of records and I can form this query and insert all the records (I am dealing with a few 1000 at a time). The issue is I need to `id` to pass to the next method.

I cannot see any way of getting the Ids currently and all searches have come up empty for me. Therefore I am forced to use this method for example.

```
foreach($allDataProcessed AS $v)
{
    $model = new Destination;
    $model->date = $v['date'];
    $model->src = $v['src'];
    $model->dst = $v['dst'];
    if($model->ignore->save())
        $ids[] = $model->id;
}
```

The issue here is obviously the amount of times I am having to interact with the database. If I have 1000 records to insert we have gone from one database call to 1000 database calls, not to mention any calls in further methods.

I have considered the possibility of inserting later in the process but I have many other methods and database calls etc that occur later and I would prefer not to do all of the processing if the record is simply duplicated which many of them will be.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your id auto_increment ?

Comment: @NeerajKumar Yes my table uses an auto incremented id. Another point to mention is that the table always increments by 1.

Comment: Then you can get the last row id before inserting and
$sql ="INSERT IGNORE INTO test(date, src, dst) VALUES ('2014-01-15','1','2') ('2014-01-12','9','2')";
$added =  Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->execute();

after this again get the last row id and you will get all the ids's in between of it.

Hence only 3 queries only 3 database interaction

Comment: @NeerajKumar Presumably though if something else is processing using the same methods at the same time, I could potentially have one process read the last id, the next one inserts and the initial is none the wiser another insert has occurred and therefore the id is one less than true. I don't see anyway to solve this without the id being returned there and then and I can't even ensure with a count of the values I was inserting as they won't always be inserted if they are duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

i hope i can help you out !

The first thing to know is that yii has a method to get last inserted row ...

```
Yii::app()->db->getLastInsertID();
```

After that i would say that you may be interested in using transactions to guarantee everything works as expected ... i leave you sort of algorithm

```
$transaction = Yii::app()->db->beginTransaction();
// do your things as needed

// things go sweet
$transaction->commit();

// if things get wild...
$transaction->rollback();
```